# How to uninstall npm package?

Tags: gruntjs, npm, uninstallation

I've installed `grunt` using `sudo npm install grunt` and now I can't remove it.

I've tried:

```
$ sudo npm uninstall grunt
```

But it gives me a `WARN`:

> ```
> npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/kuba/projects/node_modules: "grunt-cli"
> ```

I've also tried `rm`, `remove` and `unlink`. and `-g` options, but those give:

> ```
> npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/lib/node_modules: "grunt"
> ```

But I still can run `grunt` from command line.

**EDIT**:

```
$ whereis grunt
grunt: /usr/local/bin/grunt
$ file /usr/local/bin/grunt
/usr/local/bin/grunt: symbolic link to `../lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt'
$ ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules
grunt jshint
$ ls /usr/lib/node_modules
bower  csslint  devtools-terminal  npm  plato
```

Why I have 2 directories with `npm`? Is it safe to just delete them?

**EDITOR NOTE**:

*This question was asked over 5 years ago as **How to uninstall npm package**. It's been a very useful question favourited by many, who found a solution to their problem, so I'm changing it back from a recent edit that called it **How to uninstall grunt package**, because it requires the same procedure as any other `npm` package.*

Comment: I think that I have old npm modules left from old version of Xubuntu. I've start from 10 or 11 and updated to 13.10. I just delete those files.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get purge grunt`?

Comment: @Jobin there is not such package. I also search in synaptics - no grunt.

Comment: @Jobin probably old nmp install it and when Xubuntu update npm, the files just left there.

Comment: try `npm update` and then `npm uninstall grunt`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**To uninstall a `npm` module from project `node_modules` folder, run:**

`npm uninstall <module> --save`

Note that `npm` modules should be uninstalled from the same directory that contains the `node_modules` folder when running this command. The `--save` option will also remove it from your `package.json`

One can also remove a local dependency/module installation, by deleting its directory from the local `node_modules` folder. Yes, it's safe to delete dependencies there.

**To uninstall a `npm` module that was installed globally, run:**

`npm uninstall -g <module>`

It doesn't matter where you run this command from.

**To install a `npm` module, run:** (only meant as reference)

`npm install <module>`

...or:

`npm install` (if there's a `package.json` file at the root of your project)

...or:

`npm install <module> --save-dev` (if you want to add a minimum version to the dependency)

**Good things to know about *Grunt***:

- If you have installed `grunt` stable before February 18, 2013 ([the day `grunt v0.4.x` was released](http://gruntjs.com/blog/2013-02-18-grunt-0.4.0-released)), you might have an older `grunt` version still lingering in your system. That's because `grunt` versions lower than `0.4.x` were installed globally, which caused a lot of pain when upgrading/maintaining versions.
- `grunt` and `grunt-cli` are two different things.

  - `grunt` (without the "cli") is usually installed at the project level (when listed as a `devDependency` in `package.json`) by running `npm install`. That's also known as a *local installation*.
  - `grunt-cli` is the underlying foundation on which local versions of `grunt` run in different projects/folders. It *can* be installed locally, but is more useful when installed globally, once.
- `grunt` is only installed locally (by running `npm install grunt`).
- `grunt-cli` is *preferably* installed globally (by running `npm install -g grunt-cli`). `grunt-cli` official `npm` page [still warns against](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cli) installing `grunt` (without the cli) globally.
- If you want to uninstall the global installation of `grunt-cli`, run `npm uninstall -g grunt-cli`. [This issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/751) on [gruntjs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt)'s project supports this procedure.
- **Never install `grunt` globally** (by running `npm install -g grunt`).

**On `npm` and `sudo`**

**`sudo`** doesn't play well with `npm`. Only use it if you must. Below are two quotes on the advantages and disadvantages on its use:

Quoting *Isaac Z. Schlueter* on his [Introduction to npm](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm) article:

> I strongly encourage you not to do package management with sudo!
>   Packages can run arbitrary scripts, which makes sudoing a package manager command
>   as safe as a chainsaw haircut. Sure, it's fast and definitely going to cut
>   through any obstacles, but you might actually want that obstacle to stay there.
>
> I recommend doing this once instead:
>
> `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`
>
> That sets your user account as the owner of the /usr/local directory, so that you can
>   just issue normal commands in there. Then you won't ever have to use sudo when you
>   install node or issue npm commands.
>
> It's much better this way. /usr/local is supposed to be the stuff you installed, after all.

Yet another catch mentioned by [Andrei Karpushonak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701875/andrei-karpushonak):

> There are certain security concerns and functionality limitations
>   regarding changing the ownership of /usr/local to the current user:
>
> - if there is another user on the machine who could use global
>     npm packages - do not change the ownership of /usr/local
> - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/are-my-permissions-for-usr-local-correct
> - https://askubuntu.com/questions/261326/is-it-safe-to-chown-usr-local
>
> Having said that, if you want to install global module without using sudo,
>   I don't see any better solution (from pragmatic point of view) than mentioned.
>   Security vs easy of use is very broad topic, and there is no easy answer for that
>   - it just depends on your requirements.

Comment: This did not work for me: `npm uninstall packagename --save` but this did: `npm uninstall --save packagename`.  The position of the flag seemed to make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

This same thing happened with me. On doing

```
which grunt
```

I got path /usr/local/bin/. There was a folder grunt inside this.
But on running command (even from within the path /usr/local/bin/):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g grunt
```

Got the warning uninstall not installed

Solution: turns out that I installed using command

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

And while trying to remove was just typing grunt.

So once I run

```
sudo npm uninstall -g grunt-cli
```

grunt got removed.

Although you have mention in question that you run

```
sudo npm install grunt
```

But still check if you are also doing the same mistake and run it with grunt-cli.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it may be necessary to use npm's "remove a package," feature.

[npm  - Remove a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rm)

Description

"This uninstalls a package, completely removing everything npm installed on its behalf."

On your third code block, you posted this message:

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/kuba/projects/node_modules: "grunt-cli"
```

I've found that using the

```
which grunt
```

or the

```
whereis grunt
```

commands in the CLI/console provides an incomplete and confusing output.

Both of these commands will return the path of the **grunt-cli** installation, but return this simply as **grunt**.

Also using,

```
which grunt-cli
```

or the

```
whereis grunt-cli
```

fails to return any output to the CLI console.  I believe that this is a namespace issue/feature with npm.

I also had a situation where I was unable to uninstall the grunt-cli with npm's uninstall function as recommended by other contributors above.

The only thing that worked for me was using the **npm remove function with the program's full name** as demonstrated below.

```
npm rm -g grunt-cli
```

This should return the following to your console.

```
unbuild grunt-cli@#.##.#
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Weirdly, not even this worked for me.  I just deleted the soft link in my node bin folder.  After that I was able to `npm install -g grunt-cli` and `npm rm -g grunt-cli` with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use first this one

```
which grunt-cli
```

Or

```
which grunt
```

And this will show you the path to the module

In my case it was in the /usr/local/bin/

Once I got into the bin folder I just wrote

```
sudo rm grunt
```

And that was the end of it :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's installed globally add `-g` to `uninstall` and probably you will need `sudo`

```
sudo npm uninstall -g grunt
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the accepted solution's commands didn't work for me. Running `which grunt` would result in `/usr/local/bin/grunt`, but normal (or sudo) `npm uninstall -g grunt-cli` had no effect.

This is the command that finally worked for me:

```
sudo npm uninstall grunt-cli -g --prefix=/usr/local
```

Thanks to [gengxuelei on github](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/751#issuecomment-223884530) for the solution!