# yo: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, npm, yeoman

I've installed nodejs with chris lea's version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Than installed yeoman, grund-cli and bower using npm:

```
sudo npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
```

Everything went alright including the "[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks alright!" at the end of yeoman's install.

```
/home/gabriela/npm/bin/yo -> /home/gabriela/npm/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js
> yo@1.1.2 postinstall /home/gabriela/npm/lib/node_modules/yo
> node ./scripts/doctor
```

Than I run:

```
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:~$ which node
/usr/bin/node
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:~$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:~$ which bower
/usr/bin/bower
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:~$ which yo
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:~$ yo
yo: command not found
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME:$JRE_HOME
```

What went wrong? Do I have to execute any other command to install yeoman properly?

Comment: which node version are you running

Comment: "node -v" gives me "v0.10.28"

Comment: what about npm --version

Comment: that's your problem -I beleive-  take a look at my answer

Comment: According to this link [Node v0.10.28 (Stable)](http://blog.nodejs.org/2014/05/02/node-v0-10-28-stable/), node v0.10.28 works with npm at 1.4.9.

Comment: this has nothing to do with node/npm compatibility, it is because yo auto install grunt and you need to remove it before installing yo.

Answer (score 10):

I really don't know why the heck it got lost. So after a bunch of tests I resolved creating a symbolic link.

```
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:/$ sudo ln -s /home/gabriela/npm/bin/yo /usr/bin/yo
gabriela@Gabriela-Ubuntu:/$ yo
[?] What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
‣ Run the Angular-bootstrap generator (0.4.1) 
  Update your generators 
  Install a generator 
  Find some help 
  Get me out of here!
```

Comment: That really worked! You should mark your own answer as accepted, it is perfectly OK and may give a hint to future users that this is a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation [getting started](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Getting-Started) `yo` will install `bower` and `grunt`.
what you need to do is to delete `grunt` and `yo` then re-install just `yo`

```
npm uninstall -g grunt yo

npm install -g yo

npm install -g yo
```

> If you are using npm 1.2.10 or above, this will also automatically
>   install grunt and bower for you. If you're on an older version of npm,
>   you will need to install them manually
>
> If you have installed Grunt globally in the past, you will need to
>   remove it first: npm uninstall -g grunt

Comment: I got a 'not installed in /home/gabriela/npm/lib/node_modules: "grunt"' and 'not installed in /home/gabriela/npm/lib/node_modules: "yo"' but bower got uninstalled: 'unbuild bower@1.3.4'.

Comment: @GabrielaVasselai - check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642655/how-to-uninstall-npm-package) on how to uninstall

Comment: Sorry, I forgot -g when uninstalling grunt-cli and yo. Now I got a 'unbuild yo@1.1.2' and also a 'unbuild grunt-cli@0.1.13' but grunt-cli I had to uninstall with sudo. First try gave me a 'Please try running this command again as root/Administrator'.