# NodeJs npm WARN uninstall not installed in $HOME/node_modules

Tags: linux, node.js, module, npm, uninstallation

I have NodeJs module installed on **/usr/lib/node_modules/**

If i want to uninstall: `$ npm remove <module>`

I get this error message:

`npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/<user>/node_modules: "<module>"`

OS: Manjaro Linux / 0.8.13rc1 / Ascella / XFCE

Thanks!

Comment: Read this : 
[stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642655/how-to-uninstall-npm-package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ npm remove -g <module>
```

Modules installed in `/usr/lib/node_modules/` are **global**, meaning you must pass `-g` (`--global`) flag to npm in order to install/remove them. `npm install <module>` installs modules locally by default.