# Grunt only runs default task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, osx-mavericks

Using OSX Maveriks, iTerminal, zsh.

Problem: Grunt runs only the default task regardless of the task you specify.
Problem: It only happens in 1 computer.

What can be the reason for grunt not to run but the default task. I've been working with Grunt for a long time now and we use it at the company I work at. Everything has been working perfectly smooth except for 1 single coworker that when he runs `grunt myTask` is **like** if he were running just `grunt`, even if I run a made up task like `grunt myNotExistentTask` it ignores it and again **looks** like it runs `grunt`.

I did check for stupid errors:

1. Checked that I'm accessing the same project folder (multiple times).
2. I deleted the default task to see if it complained and it does.
3. I checked that the Gruntfile was not throwing errors. Then I forced to throw errors to see if it would complain, and it does.
4. Runned `npm install`.
5. Check both bashrc and zshrc for a grunt command or something.
6. Obviously grunt is accessible.
7. Runned it in the default terminal and in iTerm.
8. "Have you try to turn it on and off?" Yes I did restar the laptop.
9. I tried with multiple coworkers laptops and it only happens in the one laptop.

I did **not** have time to (but I will check for these):

1. test creating a simple Gruntfile somewhere else in his laptop, but I have a weird feeling that it would behave the same way.
2. reinstall grunt. Would that help?
3. `grunt --version` or others for that matter, I assumed that it has the specified version in the `package.json`.

we are using:

```
"grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
"grunt": "^0.4.4"
```

The code is not causing the issue here because every computer runs it but one. I can't show the actual code but I can give you the boilerplate just in case there is some mysterious thing I don't know about:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg : grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),

    someTask : {
      options : {

      },
      target1 : {

      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("dependency1");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("dependency2");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("etc");

  grunt.registerTask("default", function () {
    // creates a server with one of the dependencies
  });

  grunt.registerTask("w", function () {
    // creates a watch with one of the dependencies
  });

};
```

There is a reason behind why we are not simply doing something like `grunt.registerTask("default", [".."])`. Basically, our projects are too big and we need to change settings for each task to increase performance (e.g. not to watch too many files, etc).

I googled this different ways and couldn't find anything about this happening before. Any ideas are welcomed.

## Edit

I forgot to mention that he has been working with the project for a while, we just recently noticed because he never needed to use any other task but the default task until a few days ago when he needed to use a different task, in summary, we don't know when or why it started.

Comment: Hi camou, I've the same environment but I never been in trouble with this kind of issue. I'd like following the thread to find out what could be the problem. A stupid question: all modules in your project are installed with root permission (when needed)?

Comment: What tasks are listed when you run `grunt --help`?

Comment: and what is the result of running `which grunt` on his machine?

Comment: Ok, so we manage to find what it was thanks to you @XavierPriour. We run `type -a grunt` and it turned out to have 2 paths for grunt. I'm going to add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:

1. Deleting and cloning the repo.
2. Deleting npm_modules.
3. Reinstalling everything.
4. Creating an isolated project to test this issue.

and failing, we checked for the paths to grunt thanks to a comment by @XavierPriour

Using zsh with iTerm:

```
➜  folder git:(branch) which grunt
/usr/local/bin/grunt
➜  folder git:(branch) type -a grunt
grunt is /usr/local/bin/grunt
grunt is /usr/bin/grunt
```

We deleted the extra grunt binary:

```
➜  folder git:(branch) cd /usr/bin
➜  bin sudo -rm grunt
```

And everything started working correctly. I assume the issue is he installed grunt globally instead of just grunt-cli, although I'm not sure.

The most popular answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642655/how-to-uninstall-npm-package) shows the *dos and don'ts* of how to install grunt.